# 2D CFT for a senior undergraduate

Tags: resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory, education

I'm a senior undergraduate having a good background in QM, Linear Algebra, Tensor Calculus, Complex Analysis, and GR. This year I'm doing my graduation project on 2D CFT (especially aiming towards conformal and modular bootstrapping), so I downloaded some material (specifically Introduction to CFT with application to string theory) and started working on them, however I found myself struggling to understand most of the derivations.
Is there any source that presents this material in a completely straightforward manner or any other sources that would help me understand?

Comment: I haven't completed them but the 40-page long chapter on 2d CFT in David Tong lectures on String theory will be helpful. They require just the background you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I think an excellent source from your perspective would be *Conformal field theory on the plane* by Sylvain Ribault. You can find the arxiv version [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4290), and there is also a github with the more up-to-date version.

It is modern, and focuses explicitly on the bootstrap approach.